# Join DQL when intermediate table has not entity mapped

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, dql

I'm building a repository method to look if a `fos_group` is assigned to any `fos_user` before allowing group to be deleted. Basically this is the raw query I'm trying to make using DQL:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    fos_user u
LEFT JOIN fos_user_user_group fug ON (fug.user_id = u.id)
WHERE
    fug.group_id = :group_id
```

This is how I setup the relationship between `Users` and `Groups`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

And this is what I have done til now:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
        ->select('COUNT(gr.id)')
        ->from("UserBundle:Group", "gr");

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

But I'm stuck since I do not know how to add the `join` sentence with not mapped table/entity (`fos_user_user_group`), can anyone give me some push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped your property there you are in right way just join the property `$groups` in user entity it will join your junction table `fos_user_user_group` and the use what ever you where clause is

```
 $qb
    ->select('COUNT(g.id)')
    ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
    ->join('u.groups g')
    ->where('g.id = :val')
    ->setParameter('val',$your_group_id);
```